# PHP: For each anchor tag

Tags: php, html, for-loop, anchor, each

I currently have a side bar on my website, titled "Services", which I wish to populate with categories such as "Windows", "Linux", "Android". As all of these 'categories' exist in one page (services.php), and I had an idea to anchor each of them so I could create a list of quick-links (services.php/#Windows, services.php/#Linux and so on). What I would like to do is use a PHP function to pull all of the anchors I have created on the `Services.php` page into a side bar, so that if I edit services.php and include `<a id="tips">Other useful things</a>`, the side-bar automatically contains a link to that anchor. Sort of like a "for each anchor on this page, make a link to thispage.php/#anchor-name".

I hope this question is easier to understand than my first one. I realize I wasn't very clear.

I'm aware I could use a database table for this, but I would like it to be very simple to administer.

Comment: A bit generic since we don't know how those links are generated

Comment: Is there a code? No code, No Answer!

Comment: I'll change my question to make it a little more clear.

Comment: Updated original question. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5):

a generic answer:

For instance, let's say you have a navbar with id = anchors where your anchors rest.

Example HTML:

```
$html = '<html>(...)
<div id="anchors">
    <a href="anchor1.php">link number 1</a>
    <a href="anchor2.php">another link</a>
</div>
(...)
</html>';
```

---

Example function:

```
function findAnchors($html)
{
    $links = array();
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $navbars = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
    foreach ($navbars as $navbar) {
        $id = $navbar->getAttribute('id');
        if ($id === "anchors") {
            $anchors = $navbar->getElementsByTagName('a');
            foreach ($anchors as $a) {
                $links[] = $doc->saveHTML($a);
            }
        }
    }
    return $links;
}
```

this will return an array with all links.

Output:

```
array
  0 => string '<a href="anchor1.php">link number 1</a>' (length=39)
  1 => string '<a href="anchor2.php">another link</a>' (length=38)
```

---

Edit base on OP comment:

Unless you "tag" them somehow, its not trivial. One way would be to add a class to each anchor and then transverse the whole document.

Example:

HTML

```
$html = '<html>(...)
<a class="anchor" href="anchor1.php">link number 1</a>
(... stuff in here)
<a class="anchor" href="anchor2.php">another link</a>
(...)
</html>';
```

Function:

```
function findAnchors($html)
{
    $links = array();
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $aTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($aTags as $a) {
        $class = $a->getAttribute('class');
        if ($class === "anchor") {
            $links[] = $doc->saveHTML($a);
        }
    }
    return $links;
}
```

Comment: This looks spot on minor a few tweaks. The only problem I can see is that I would like these anchor tags to be spread out, for instance: ``<anchor>Hello</anchor>Welcome to my website..<anchor>Bye</anchor>Goodbye``. I wouldn't be containing all anchors together inside of a div.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have something like a `link` and a `name` pair, yeah, you will be using [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) function here. Say you have something like:

```
$links = array(
    "index.html" => "Home",
    "about.html" => "About Us",
    "contact.html" => "Contact Us"
);
```

You can use this code to display it:

```
foreach ($links as $link => $name) {
    echo "<a href=\"$link\">'$name'</a>";
}
```

And it gets displayed this way:

```
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="about.html">About Us</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Hi, almost. As I said to Tivie who gave a similar response, I am looking to avoid creating static data (such as an array). Tivie was on point with his function, but I am looking foreach anchor tag in a page (and not a particular array, or div section). I have updated my original question to give a better understanding. Thanks